# Using .zip files with Forge Design Automation for AutoCAD

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I have a zip file containing several file types (.dwg,.xlsx,.pdf).  If I specify a .zip file as input, I've noticed they're all accepted by Forge, but only .dwg's come back out.  Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "only dwg's come back out"? Are you saying that you provide a link to zip as an input argument and when it is unzipped other files "disappear". Can you point to a workitem ID were this happened?

Comment: The .zip file that comes back doesn't contain other file types. Only dwg's.   workItemStatus.id = "249f7d79f45247bab6983c093aa969c5".

Comment: Charles, this will depends on how you defined the Activity. If it is a single file DWG as output, then only DWG( It also assumes your script/plugin save as a DWG).  If you want to have a zip , the Activity needs to define it as zip. In your plugin, save all outputs to the zip folder, Design Automation will package them for you. This is a blog on Revit, but may be a reference: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-generate-dynamic-number-output-design-automation-revit-v3

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I looked at the workitem in question and I don't see anything odd here. We downloaded your zip and unzipped it. We don't try to process the files in the zip in any shape or form. If the zip contains non-dwg files the file will be in the working folder of the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your results to specific folder and finally create zip file.

`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(CurrentDirectory + "\\Result", CurrentDirectory + "\\Result.zip");`

This zip file set as result of your WorkItem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who replied,
Ultimately, I create a project folder structure all my files are unzipped into (dwgs, pdfs, xlsx),beneath the working folder.  My localname for both my input and result are identical in both the Activity and the Workitem.  I recall Augusto telling me not to do this, but I have yet to run into an issue with it.  In the end, my files get cycled in AutoCAD Core and saved to same location. DA zips the changed files and sends them to my endpoint.  I took this approach, because if I save to changed files into a results folder, my modified dwg files and non-dwg files are now in two separate, adjacent locations.  If there's a side affect of working with files in a single location, I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: Looking back at this, I'd like to comment, since you're basically buying processing time, it really makes no sense to push non-dwg file types through the system.  The only exception I have is a linked Excel file.  I separated the dwg's out into it's own .zip file and processed those.  I'll later recombine the entire package into a single .zip and download it.